# byobu scrolling and text selection

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, byobu

I want [byobu](https://byobu.org/) running in gnome-terminal to:

1. Interpret mouse wheel scrolling as scrolling up in the current byobu window.
2. Allow me to select text with my mouse (eg, to copy it to the clipboard).

Is this possible? <kbd>Alt+F12</kbd> will enable #1, but prevent me from selecting text. Otherwise, selecting works fine, but scrolling scrolls through gnome-terminal, and not the current byobu window.

Answer (score 20):

You're right about <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>, for toggling mouse mode on and off.

As for scrolling in the Byobu, you'd need to enter scrollback mode, using <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: After scrolling, there is a way to select text just with keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting the text. Text will be copied (and pasted!) as if you're in `Mouse: OFF` mode.

And if you were as confused as I was about [*which* clipboard](https://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html) this will copy text to, here's what I see:

| Highlight text in... | ...with mode `Mouse: ON`... | ...with <kbd>Shift</kbd> OR mode `Mouse: OFF`... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `xterm` | => ClipboardSelection | => PrimarySelection |
| `gnome-terminal` | => ClipboardSelection | => PrimarySelection |
| `konsole` | => ClipboardSelection | => PrimarySelection |
| `alacritty` | => ClipboardSelection | => PrimarySelection AND ClipboardSelection |
| `kitty` | => ClipboardSelection | => PrimarySelection |

Comment: alacritty copies into the ClipboardSelection is because it supports OSC 52 (the other terminals use VTE which refuses to fully implement it -- due to potential/theoretical security issues)

Answer (score -1):

> SCROLLBACK, COPY, PASTE MODES
>          Each  window  in Byobu has up to 10,000 lines of scrollback history, which you can enter and navigate using the alt-pgup and
>   alt-pgdn keys.  Exit
>          this scrollback mode by hitting enter.  You can also easily copy and paste text from scrollback mode.  To do so, enter scrollback
>   using  alt-pgup
>          or  alt-pgdn,  press  the  spacebar  to start highlighting text, use up/down/left/right/pgup/pgdn to select the text, and press
>   enter to copy the
>          text.  You can then paste the text using alt-insert or ctrl-a-].

Above taken from: https://gist.github.com/inhumantsar/bf86ff1961cccdf8be06

NOTE: This copies into byobu(or tmux's) clipboard, I've not found a way of pasting outside of the byobo terminal yet.